# Will "academic expert" for study website hurt me on the academic job market?

Tags: job-search, job, online-learning

I've been offered a side job working to answer submitted student questions (at my own discretion) related to my field of expertise for a study website. Seems pretty harmless as a way to earn very minor extra cash.

Would this have any implications for my prospects through the academic job market? I probably wouldn't list it on a CV, but would a committee seeing this kind of activity see it as a bad thing?

Comment: If it does, I would not work for an institution that consider that kind of job as something negative. 

We all have to eat and live at the level that we like and  getting some more cash to achieve that should not be seen as a negative.

Comment: Is this something like "CourseHero" or a site that also does ghostwriting? Even if you choose to only answer ethically on such sites, an association with such sites may be seen negatively.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see it being harmfull to your career if you don't answer asignment questions or doing something that can be thought as unethical. may be you can elaborate on why you think that it can harm your career?

Comment: Possibly the interpretation that this activity could help students get answers to homework that they should do themselves. Especially those students who pay to avail this service.

Comment: Than, You should really check the site and be sure that the site has some policy/policies against cheeting. If someone asks about it in a interview, you can  tell them they are ethical. It might even be helpfull in as a teaching experience. You can claim that because you interacted with students in a QNA site, you improved your communication skills etc.